# The standard Python 3.6 module tries to call python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml-parsing, python-3.6, python-module

I am using python 3.6.8. When I try to import pyexpat, I get a "Module use of python38.dll conflicts with this version of Python." conflict. I checked the documentation and this module should be supported from at least 2.x+ python version. I've tried running my script both through the conda environment through visual studio (python 3.6.8) and through a priginal python 3.6.6 and 3.6.8. I am getting this error anyway.
It is very strange. How can python version 3.6.8, which I just downloaded from the official site, refer to version 3.8 if it is a clean new installed version?
There are too few tutorials on this module, but it should definitely work from early versions of python.

Have any ideas what can be done? I repeat once again that I literally run unmodified python without any modules and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I suspect `expat` is the module that is referring to `python38.dll`, not yours, and not your Python interpreter. In your shoes I would install 3.8 alongside 3.6 and see if that makes the problem go away.

Comment: By official site, do you mean one of the links [on this page](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-368/)?  If not, try actually installing the official version and ensure that you only run this new installation.